# Delete rows if column values are equal

Tags: r, rows

I want delete the rows if the columns (YEAR, POL, CTY, ID, AMOUNT) are equal in the values across all rows. Please see the output table below.

```
Table:

YEAR  POL    CTY   ID   AMOUNT   RAN     LEGAL
2017  30408  11    36   3500     RANGE1  L0015N20W23
2017  30408  11    36   3500     RANGE1  L00210N20W24
2017  30408  11    36   3500     RANGE1  L00310N20W25
2017  30409  11    36   3500     RANGE1  L0015N20W23
2017  30409  11    35   3500     RANGE2  NANANA
2017  30409  11    35   3500     RANGE3  NANANA
2017  30409  11    35   3500     RANGE3  NANANA
```

Output:

```
YEAR  POL    CTY   ID   AMOUNT   RAN     LEGAL
2017  30408  11    35   3500     RANGE1  L0015N20W23
```

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df[,1:5]),]`

Comment: Thanks. But, I just realized there are rows which has Legal info. In that case, I need to keep the rows. Please see the revised table above.

Comment: I'm confused by your output - your input has 2 different `POL` values, but your output only has 1, so do you want to ignore POL in assessing duplicates? And you added `LEGAL` in an edit, but again your output didn't change, so what's the meaning of your comment *"rows which has Legal info. In that case, I need to keep the rows"*?

Comment: @user8848543 can you also update the output. I assume that you want to keep all the first four rows. right? p.s. if that's the case `df[!(duplicated(df[,-6]) | duplicated(df[,-6], fromLast = TRUE)), ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
no_duplicate_cols <- c("YEAR", "POL", "CTY", "ID", "AMOUNT")

new_df <- df[!duplicated(df[, no_duplicate_cols]), ]
```

The data frame `new_df` will hold the rows from `df` that are not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly then I think you can try this

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(YEAR, POL, CTY, ID, AMOUNT) %>%
  filter(n() == 1)
```

Output (but it seems that the output provided in the original question has bit of typo!):

```
# A tibble: 1 x 7
# Groups:   YEAR, POL, CTY, ID, AMOUNT [1]
   YEAR   POL   CTY    ID AMOUNT    RAN       LEGAL
1  2017 30409    11    36   3500 RANGE1 L0015N20W23
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(YEAR = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L), POL = c(30408L, 30408L, 30408L, 30409L, 30409L, 30409L, 
30409L), CTY = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), ID = c(36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 35L, 35L), AMOUNT = c(3500L, 3500L, 3500L, 
3500L, 3500L, 3500L, 3500L), RAN = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("RANGE1", "RANGE2", "RANGE3"), class = "factor"), 
    LEGAL = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("L0015N20W23", 
    "L00210N20W24", "L00310N20W25", "NANANA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("YEAR", 
"POL", "CTY", "ID", "AMOUNT", "RAN", "LEGAL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```